# jquery code not working in IE6/7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Hello dear members of stackoverflow, I have a question , why this code isn't working in IE6/7/8 versions :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
(function(){
$("#divas").hide();
var counter = 3;
var elm = document.getElementById("divas");
setInterval(function() {
counter--;
if (counter >= 0) {
  span = document.getElementById("count");
  span.innerHTML = counter;
}
// Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
if (counter === 0) {
    $("#main").load("secretptpsiteonlyadmin.php?id=" + elm.innerHTML);
    clearInterval(counter);
 }

 }, 1000);

 })();

 };
 /script>
```

Code gets data from another php file when timer reaches zero. I think problem is somewhere in innerHTML or in variable connection.

Comment: Because jQuery 2.0 doesn't support those browsers.

from http://jquery.com/download/: jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(document).ready(function(){ .... });
```

instead

```
window.onload = function(){
```

Comment: No, its all about jquery version. As kalley commented jquery 2.xx doesn't support these kind of browsers.

Comment: so , we can forget it now :)